# Как получить значение параметра Dajngo Rest Framework

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

Мне нужно значение параметра pk в классе представления , но он его не получает ,вывел к консоль значение `pk` но оно равно `None`. Запрос вот такой отправлял `api/vds/some/5/`
Как получить значение pk?

urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/vds/product/', ProductList.as_view()),
    path('api/vds/category/', CategoryList.as_view()),
    path('api/vds/maker/', MakerList.as_view()),
    path('api/vds/some/<int:pk>/',GetSome.as_view()),
    path('api/vds/productdetail/<int:pk>/', DetailProduct.as_view()),
]
```

views

```
class GetSome(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer

    def get_family_tree(self):
        children = self.parent.all()

        if not children:
            return {'name': self.name, 'children': []}

        return {
            'name': self.name,
            'categories': [self.get_family_tree(child) for child in children],
        }

    def get_queryset(self):
        pk = self.request.data.get("pk")
        print(pk)
        categories = Category.objects.get(id=pk).get_family_tree(self)
        return Product.objects.filter(category__parent__in=categories)
```

Serializer

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'description', 'category', 'maker']
        depth = 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Измените функцию get_queryset

```
def get_queryset(self):
    pk = self.kwargs['pk']
    print(pk)
    categories = Category.objects.get(id=pk).get_family_tree(self)
    return Product.objects.filter(category__parent__in=categories)
```